# How can I reprogram a wireless music receiver to turn it into a mp3 player?

Tags: audio, usb, mp3, media-player, jack

I was wondering if it is possible to transform a **wireless music receiver** into a **mp3 player**.

As a wireless music receiver has both a jack and a usb, I was wondering if it could somehow be hacked to function as a mp3 player instead.

If you have some leads on how to achieve this, I would greatly appreciate. Thanks!

I haven't tried anything yet. I was wondering if I could reformat the device and write a program to make it work as a mp3 player.